# If $k$ is a field, then the existence of an isomorphism $A \cong A^*$ implies automatically that $A$ is finite-dimensional.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. We say that $A$ is symmetric if $A$ is
fnitely generated projective as a $k$-module and if $A \cong A^*$ as $A-A$-bimodules, where $A^* = \operatorname{Hom}_{k}(A,k)$.

If $k$ is a field, then the existence of an isomorphism $A \cong A^*$ implies automatically that $A$ is finite-dimensional.

I couldn't figure out why it automatically implies this. Thank you!

Comment: What's $A^*{}$?

Comment: Try it the other way round - if $A$ is infinitely dimensional, what does that say about $A^*$ (and $A^{**}$)?

Comment: Sorry Kolja, still not clear to me. $A^*$ would be infinitely dimensional as well?

Comment: The algebraic dual of an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ has strictly greater dimension than $V$. See for example [this](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/dualspaceinfinite.pdf) writeup by Keith Conrad.